# How to set up cron using curl command?

Tags: perl, curl, cron, wget

After `apache` rebuilt my `cron` jobs stopped working. 
I used the following command:

```
wget -O - -q -t 1 http://example.com/cgi-bin/loki/autobonus.pl
```

Now my DC support suggests me to change the `wget` method to `curl`. What would be the correct value in this case?

Comment: What happens if you run the command manually? `wget` should cover your needs here. Try running it  without the `-q` option to get a more detailed output.

Comment: If I run http://example.com/cgi-bin/loki/autobonus.pl in my browser, everything works fine. ust changed to wget without -q. The following error occured: Resolving example.com... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to example.com|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-12-23 07:38:01 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Comment: You might have a problem with your web server listening for that virtualhost only on your public IP and not on localhost. So when you use the domain with the external IP in combination it works, but on the server there might be an entry in the `/etc/hosts` file that points it to `127.0.0.1`. Can you check that?

Comment: Also change passwords as you left the domain in one of your comments and it displayed the credentials ....

Comment: I was told that my crontab file is missing. Can it be true? How to check it?

Comment: You can check that with `crontab -l` on most systems however it depends on the setup. But as long the command fails when you run manually there's no point in figuring out the cron part yet. Also, CHANGE PASSWORD :)

Comment: Here is the content of my hosts file: 127.0.0.1  localhost example.com
127.0.0.1  localhost.localdomain localhost
::1  localhost localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

50.62.35.162  ip-50-62-35-162.secureserver.net ip-50-62-35-162

Comment: On the contrary, the script works fine if I launch it manually in my browser! Just a cron job isn't working.

Comment: Try removing the `127.0.0.1 localhost example.com` line and run the command manually again.

Comment: I am sorry if this sounds stupid, but I cannot edit the files in WinSCP since stupid godaddy system doesn't allow me to login as root. I can login as root in SSH, but I don't know which commands should I enter. Maybe you can teach me how to edit files in Putty?

Comment: Just create a copy that you can edit, edit that, then copy it over the original one.

Comment: I mean that I get an error when I try to replace hosts file in WinSCP: Permission denied.
Error code: 3
Error message from server: Permission denied
In WinSCP, I cannot login as root, due to stupid godaddy rules. So can I edit hosts in Putty? If yes, then how?

Comment: I've posted an answer that gets around this issue

Answer (score 0):

`-O -` is equivalent to curl's default behavior, so that's easy.

`-q` is curl's `-s` (or `--silent`)

`--retry N` will substitute for `wget`'s `-t N`

All in all:

```
curl -s --retry 1 http://example.com/cgi-bin/loki/autobonus.pl
```

Comment: I tried this command, it doesn't work :( Then I removed -s. The following error occured: curl: (56) Failure when receiving data from the peer

Answer (score 0):

try run change with the full path of wget

```
/usr/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1 http://example.com/cgi-bin/loki/autobonus.pl
```

you can find the full path with:

```
which wget
```

and more, check if you can reach the destination domain with ping or other methods:

```
ping example.com
```

---

Update:

based on the comments, seems to be caused by the line in /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com   #change example.com to the real domain
```

Comment: based on your comment, you may have an record in /etc/hosts with the domain point to 127.0.0.1, thus get 404 response

Comment: The website works fine, just pinged it. Here is what I get: Resolving example.com... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to example.com|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-12-23 07:44:01 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Comment: So what should I write instead of 127.0.0.1?

Comment: But that's the thing, if you ping it from elsewhere you get xx.xx.35.162. So your web server configuration probably only listens on that for your virtual host. You probably want to remove the entry from your host file that looks like `127.0.0.1 example.com`

Comment: 1. run `netstat -ntlp | grep :80` and see the output. 2.try to change this line to `xx.xx.35.162 example.com`

Comment: Here i the output to the command: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LIST         EN      905/httpd

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have restricted options in terms that on the server where the cron should run you have the domain pinned to `127.0.0.1` but the virtual host configuration does not work with that.

What you can do is to let `wget` connect by IP but send the `Host` header so that the virtual host matching would work:

```
wget -O - -q -t 1 --header 'Host: example.com' http://xx.xx.35.162/cgi-bin/loki/autobonus.pl
```

**Update**

Also probably you don't need to run this over the web server, so why not just run:

```
perl /path/to/your/script/autobonus.pl
```

Comment: Here is what I get: Connecting to xx.xx.35.162:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Giving up.

Comment: It must be some kind of network issue then. Maybe you need to use an internal IP. Run `ip addr | grep -oP 'inet \K[0-9.]+'` and try the addresses from there.

Comment: well, actually xx.xx.35.162 is present there, as well as 127.0.0.1

Comment: any other suggestions please?